# trying to move back from polyglossia to babel

Tags: babel, polyglossia, input-encodings

I am using XeLaTeX because Unicode. What am I doing wrong? I do not see the inputenc dependency (guess indirect?), and have no idea how to proceed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english, arabic, russian, german]{babel}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
    mwe
\end{document}
```

! Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.
(inputenc)                only UTF-8 supported.

Or is polyglossia not deprecated anymore (now there is a 2019 doc)?

Comment: don't use the option arabic, it loads an outdated file, use the new bidi interface from babel instead.

Comment: Off-topic: Unless your document uses no-longer-current German spelling conventions, don't use the option `german` -- use `ngerman` instead.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513618/howto-multilanguage-babel#513667 .