# Using different languages within the same document

Tags: languages

For using latex with different languages' what does one do?  I want to write versions of the same paragraphs in different languages.  Have installed `texlive`, `auctex`, and have seen some examples using `babel` (although `babel` was used to specify a single language).

I use `lualatex` to make the `pdf` file.

Comment: lualatex and xelatex I think using `pollyglossia` and not `babel`, So, `\usepackage{pollyglossia}` and then `\setmainlanguage{english}` and `\setotherlanguage{italian}` would be sufficient. You can change between languages by using `\begin{italian}` and `\end{italian}` etc. (XeLaTeX actually needs pollyglossia... lualatex possibly can handle both... not sure)

Comment: Surely you can use babel   with lualatex and xelatex. You can declare the languages you want as options when loading the package and then you can use commands `\selectlanguage` or` \foreignlanguage` to call any language you declared except with the last one declared in options which is the default. For example when loading the package  `\usepackage[english,french,greek]{babel}`, Greek is the default language and English and French are the foreign secondary languages which you can call as mentioned before.

Comment: @koleygr `Babel` fully supports pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex. Please, see the manual (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/latex3/babel/v.3.79/babel.pdf) and the `babel` site (https://latex3.github.io/babel/).

Comment: Thank you ... just remembered that I had decided to go on with polyglossia many years before for some reasons that had to do with greek. Thank you.

Comment: There are many examples here. For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513667/5735 . The `babel` manual (linked above) contains many examples (eg, in sec 1.2) and there are full document samples in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/main/samples .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,body={180mm,237mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}\setsansfont{FiraSans}\setmonofont{Consolas}
\usepackage[english,french,greek]{babel}
\begin{document}
    Αυτά είναι Ελληνικά
    
    \selectlanguage{english} This is in English
    
    Αυτή είναι η προεπιλεγμένη γλώσσα = \selectlanguage{english} This is the default language
    
    \selectlanguage{greek} Ελληνικά και πάλι!=\selectlanguage{french} Grec encore !
    
    \foreignlanguage{english}{This sentence is in English}
    
    \selectlanguage{french} C' est la vie!
    
    \foreignlanguage{french}{Je suis...}
    
    Και μετά συνεχίζεις στην προεπιλεγμένη γλώσσα.=\foreignlanguage{french}{Et puis vous continuez dans la langue par défaut.}=\foreignlanguage{english}{And then you continue in the default language.}
\end{document}
```